# Making leaflet control open by default

Tags: leaflet

I'm using leaflet to display a map.  I have a control section that I'd like to be open by default, but I can't find a way to do it through the [API](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The collapsed option in the control will achieve this. You need that null for it to work though. An example:

```
var overlays = {
    "Title1": polyLayer1,
    "Title2": polyLayer1,
    "Title3": lineLayer,
    "Title4": pointLayer
            };

L.control.layers(overlays,null,{collapsed:false}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

The curly braces with the ***collapsed*** attribute did the trick!